# Is there a way to keep the element width when 0px in height?

Tags: html, css, safari, height

I will do my best to explain my problem in detail below, but the question asked stays the same. In short my question is:

**Is there a way to make an element hidden/invisible being 0px in height or at least a considerable less amount in height than 1px but still keep the element it's width so that it will also function in Safari?**

*Full detail explanation of the issue:*

I have an issue with the CSS `min-height` property in Safari.
For instance, in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers you are allowed to use a value below `1px` for the `min-height` property. While Safari does not allow you to set a value below `1px`.

Example, I am working on an RTL issue that only happens in Safari.
It has to do with the fact that some items are conditionally hidden based on a specific value selected by the user in a form. It's essential that the items that are on the left side of the visible element(s) to have at least some height (but still invisible), otherwise the right element (which has `float:left` property) would be placed to the left until all elements on the left would be conditionally visible.

Now you could say just use `float:right` for these elements, but this is not a solution in this case because the RTL setting must be optional in the system and is a user preference, and we do not control the **order** of the elements (because the form is saved in originally none RTL state) that are lined up next to each other.

So for example in Chrome the element has set a `min-height` of `0.0105px` which works and the element has actually an height that is enough to be actively pushing other elements to the right even when conditionally invisible (that's why i can't use `display:none` in the first place because of RTL layout must stay in tact).

Now the issue is that for example Safari does not allow me to use `0.0105px` as minimum value for the `min-height` CSS property. I tested what the minimum required value was, and it was everything equal to or above `1px` for Safari. So a solution would be that you would just apply this `1px` only for safari browsers, but this is not really a desired solution in this case and I will explain why.

The system allows users to create forms, and it could be that users have for instance **50 or even more column elements** in the middle of the form that might be conditionally hidden. When this is the case it would mean that when they are all conditionally hidden the total height of them together (when all columns are 1/1 ratio in width) would be **50px**. Which is not desired and not intended when building the form by the end user.

In the Chrome example the **50px** would instead be **0.5px** which is acceptable for me.

Any thoughts on this or ideas would be much appreciated. Maybe it's a design issue in my conditional hide/show system and maybe I should take a completely different approach to make this work nicely? Any ideas are welcome.

Example of what I do at the moment which works in Safari, but I want to keep the height 0px of the 2 columns on the left:

```css
.column-wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  width:30%;
}
.column-content {
  background-color:grey;
}
.conditionally-hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  height:0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-wrapper"> <!-- column must keep it's original width, but must be 0px in height when inner content is conditionally hidden -->
  <div class="column-content conditionally-hidden">
    This content is conditionally hidden
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-wrapper"> <!-- column must keep it's original width, but must be 0px in height when inner content is conditionally hidden -->
  <div class="column-content conditionally-hidden">
    This content is conditionally hidden
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-wrapper"> <!-- column must stay on right side, because of RTL layout -->
  <div class="column-content">
    This content visible
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just reading your short question, can't you just set it to visibility: none and height: 1px then overflow: hidden;?

Comment: I don't think so, because the height would still be 1px not? The overflow hidden only makes sure elements inside it do not overlap outside their parent element. And the conditionally hidden elements already have `visibility:hidden;` (sorry that i didn't state this anywhere, i will adjust my answer)

Comment: After reading your long version, you need to post some sample code, you could probably just apply different styling for the rows depending on your html. Just paste a block or 2

Comment: Example can be found here: http://f4d.nl/dev/rtl-test-3/ (this is an example form from a client he made himself with the system).

Comment: Ok, it looks each form row is in its own container (row) so while I am not 100% sure of exactly what you want, but from I understand you can most likely solve this easily with display flex, do you know about flex? float is a thing of the past. Again if you post some sample code by editing the question, I am sure there will be a easier solution

Comment: No don't know `display:flex;`, i will look into it and see if it could possibly fix it. What is the difference of using flex property?

Comment: This here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a good guide to it. I think your issue is you want things to stay in their rows when some are missing and flex will take care of that by default. If you post sample code of just 1 row I can post an answer explaining how things work

Comment: Yes, I am reading that guide right now and testing some things, i will post some example code when I found proper solution, i think indeed the flex property might fix my problems. Also very cool the vertical align option, already learned some great new features today thanks to you! Awesome :)

Comment: This sounds like maybe you should switch to Flexbox...

Comment: @prodigitalson yes, indeed, I actually made working example which i also shared in my answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height:0;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>Simple test.
```

... creates an empty space cross-browser, cross-device having the desired `width` without displaying anything.

If the above is not enough for your case, both your time and ours is better spent if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the actual problem you're having, IMHO.

Comment: Hi, i tried this method, so far it looks like this simple solution did the trick. I am also going to do some test with the flex method suggested by @Huangism because it might solve another issue I had, because preferably I would like to use a method that does not require `overflow: hidden`. But this solved my issue so I will mark it as best answer. I didn't know that the `inline-block` in combination with `height:0` keeps the original width of the element, really nice :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, at first it looked like it would work, but not in Safari, in other browser this method does work though and height is nicely 0px. But Safari seems to give 0px height elements a width of 0px automatically. Guess only option left would be display:flex method. @Huangism

Comment: @RensTillmann, with all due respect, I believe your approach is not optimal. You wasted quite a bit of time trying to guess the cause. You drove most people capable of helping you away because you didn't provide a means to experience the bug (mcve). You wrote a long story that has little to do with whatever your issue is, without providing sufficient insight on the problem or on the desired outcome. By the way, you can test in Safari if my example works or not. Lastly, if `inline-block` doesn't help, most likely `flex` doesn't either.

Comment: I provided the URL to the issue (in comments section), but I understand that it's a quite difficult question to understand correctly. I will work on it and update so everyone understands. ps. for understanding, it's not a so called bug, it's more an issue that Safari doesn't allow min-height lower than 1px.

Comment: @Rens, out of principle, most capable coders on SO will not open an external website. When they help you, you will apply the solution. So the website will change and the question will become irrelevant to future users. In short, you ask for help but provide none to others. Most would go: *"I'd rather move to next question, thank you very much"*. Besides, a whole website is a lot of code. In a snippet you can (and *should*) remove everything that's not related to the issue, to make it easier for others to understand and help.

Comment: I updated my answer with example snippet code, of what the issue was in a simple example. I also found a work around with the suggestion made by Huangism, I posted an answer with working code example that worked for me, thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after @Huangism suggestion to take a look at the [CSS Flexbox Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) I found a solution to my problem. Working example:

```css
.row {
    background-color: red;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    align-items: flex-start; 
}
.row > .column {
    width: 30%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.row > .column.conditionally-hidden > * {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column conditionally-hidden">
      <div class="content">
          content 1
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column conditionally-hidden">
      <div class="content">
          content 2
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column conditionally-hidden">
      <div class="content">
          content 1
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column conditionally-hidden">
      <div class="content">
          content 2
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
          content 3
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```